# Create the good array

Tags: php, arrays

The final result mus be :

```
  $grammar = ['a' => '', 'an' => '', 'the' => '', 'shall' => '', 'should' => '', 'à' => '', 'un' => '', une =>''];
```

To allow more flexibility and add a new language without to populate `$grammar`, I call 2 files : grammar_french and grammar_english

These 2 files are allow to create an array with the data

```
  foreach ($files_get_array as $grammar) {
    $array_hooks[] = $this->call('SEO', $grammar['name']); // read the filename
  }
```

the result is :

```
array(2) { 
 [0]=> array(1) 
   { 
     [0]=> array(51) {
       ["a"]=> string(0) "" ["an"]=> string(0) "" ["the"]=> string(0) "" 
     } 
   } 
 [1]=> array(1) 
   { 
      [0]=> array(44) { 
        ["a"]=> string(0) "" ["à"]=> string(0) "" ["et"]=> string(0) "" 
      } 
    } 
 }
```

I recreate a loop, `array[0]` allow to have the good final result with the french and english but if I write `$grammar = $array[0];` 
I have just one language as result.

```
foreach ($array_hooks as $array) {
  $grammar = $array[0];
}
```

result `$array[0]` display the 2 languages:

```
array(51) { ["a"]=> string(0) "" ["an"]=> string(0) "" ["the"]=> string(0) "" ...


return $grammar;
```

How to write the last loop to have the 2 languages to have the good final result ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge the arrays in your loop:

```
$grammar = array();
foreach ($array_hooks as $array) {
    $grammar = array_merge($grammar, $array[0]);
}
```

Note that if you have two words spelt the same in different languages, you will only get one result in the final array.